# Existence of two basis such that a linear operator could be associated to a fixed matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am having problems to solve the following question:

> Consider the linear operator $T: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by: $$T(x,y,z,w)= (2x+y-z, x+y+w, -x).$$
>
> i.e., $T$, in relation to the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and
>   $\mathbb{R}^3$, is given by:
>
> $$[T] =\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  -1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix} $$
>
> Consider the matrix: $$ M =\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 &
>  -1 & 3 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 & -2  \end{bmatrix} $$
>
> There are bases $\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathcal{D}$ of
>   $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $[T]_{\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}} = M$ ?

I tried to fix $\mathcal{C} = \{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1) \}$ and had no success to find a basis $\mathcal{D}$.

Also, i tried to verify if the dimension if $\dim \ker T$ and $\dim Im(T)$ are preserved in the two matrices. In both cases we have $\dim \ker T = 1$.

Comment: Are you sure of you?

Comment: @ArnaudD., I didn't understood your comment.

Comment: But I think you don't have to fix a basis C as you want and then find D, instead try to solve the system of equations to find both bases

Comment: I should have been more precise. Are you sure $\dim \ker T$ and $\dim\operatorname{im} T$ are the same for the two matrices?

Comment: @ArnaudD., in both cases $\dim \ker T = 1$ and $\dim Im(T) = 3$.

Comment: @VictorRonchim I don't think so. See my answer.

Comment: @ArnaudD., you are absolutely right. I did something wrong in my calculations. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ was representing $T$ in some bases, its rank would be equal to the dimension of $\operatorname{im}(T)$, which is $3$. But actually $M$ has rank $2$, because the third column is the first one minus the second one and the fourth one is twice the second one minus the first one.